# Some item options or their combination are not currently available in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, cart, configurable-product

In a store the products are importing via a connector with clients ERP.

Variations (size attribute only) and products that are out of stock are not visible in the store.

When we try to add a product in the cart Magento randomly gives the error "Some item options or their combination are not currently available." to some variations even they are in stock and with available quantity.

For example, we have a jacket with sizes 48, 50, 52, 54, 56

We can buy only two of them (48, 50 for example) and all the others are showing the error.

 This happens almost to all products

 The website is https://onnetgr.com

Thanks in advance for any help

[image]

Comment: any luck on this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Hermano I think there is a browser cache problem